# Why does Netbeans ask for plugins which I cannot find to update?

Tags: plugins, netbeans, antlr, updates

I want to install ANTLRWorks plugin, but Netbeans says:

```
Some plugins require plugin **Editor Settings Storage** to be installed.
The plugin Editor Settings Storage is requested in implementation version 201302132200.  The following plugin is affected:       ANTLRWorks Editor 

Some plugins require plugin **Editor Options** to be installed.
The plugin Editor Options is requested in implementation version 201302132200.  The following plugin is affected:       ANTLRWorks Editor
```

I cannot find these plugins and no information in the internet about this issue (only the same questions from other people)

Any ideas how to update these plugins?

## Update:

I found that the plugin requires an older version of
`org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage` **201302132200** and I have a version **201306052037**. Can I downgrade a plugin in netbeans?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**That was because of too new version** of Netbeans. **Uninstall 7.3.1 and install 7.3** and the ANTLRWorks2 will install on it without any issues.

Comment: I think its good idea to add a note on http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks#release-notes to say this point,till ANTLRWorks is made compatible. It avoids downloading newer version of netbeans.

Comment: You can also use the plugin with NetBeans 8.0 - when you install, make sure you turn *off* the option to automatically download any updates.  This will ensure the original 8.0 NetBeans IDE is installed, which the ANTLR plugin is compatible with.  If you already have NetBeans 8.0 installed, you can uninstall it (best to uninstall the AppData as well) then reinstall with this option turned off.